# Lyx: ensure runninghead always on right

Tags: header-footer, lyx, lyx-layouts

I create a running heading with the command "runninghead" Now the running head is on every other side on the left side.

I want to print the work onesidedly so I want to get the running heading on every page on the right side.

Comment: Under *Document* -> *Settings* -> *Page Layout* is "Two-sided document" checked or not?

Comment: It is unchecked...

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enought information: especially, which heading style is used and what customization via LyX/LaTeX Preamble or TeX code/ERT are made - in other words, a minimal working example. In this form, it seems not possible to answer the question...